# How to Configure Log4Net Custom Object Renderer for Generic Objects?

Tags: generics, log4net

I have a generic object: MyGenericObject(of T), how do I register a [custom renderer](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html#Renderers) in log4net in the config file? For example, if this was a normal object the following would work:

```
<renderer renderingClass="MyObjectRenderer, MyClassLibrary" renderedClass="MyObject, MyClassLibrary" />
```

However I don't know how to write this for Generics, I attempted this:

```
<renderer renderingClass="MyObjectRenderer, MyClassLibrary" renderedClass="MyObject(Of MyNonGenericObject), MyClassLibrary" />
```

but this happened:

```
log4net:ERROR XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Could not find class [MyObject(Of MyNonGenericObject), MyClassLibrary].
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'MyObject(Of MyNonGenericObject)' from assembly 'MyClassLibrary'.
```

Does anyone have any better ideas on how to achive what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you are using in XML file, `MyObject(Of MyNonGenericObject)`, is specific to VB .NET, just like `MyObject<MyNonGenericObject>` is specific to C#.

You change your declaration to use language-independent CLR type syntax:

```
MyObject`1[[MyNonGenericObject, MyClassLibrary]], MyClassLibrary
```

(`1` after `` ` `` indicates the number of type parameters.)

So the line will be:

```
<renderer renderingClass="MyObjectRenderer, MyClassLibrary" renderedClass="MyObject`1[[MyNonGenericObject, MyClassLibrary]], MyClassLibrary" />
```