# How do I write and use/configure a log4net object renderer which renders generic collections (and uses properties)?

Tags: c#, generics, logging, log4net, log4net-configuration

I have several generic collections, say,

```
IList<MyClass>
IList<MyOtherClass>
```

**1)** How do I write a log4net IObjectRenderer for this? What I've got so far is:

```
public class ListOfMyClassRenderer : IObjectRenderer
{
    public void RenderObject(RendererMap rendererMap, object obj, TextWriter writer)
    {
        try
        {
                var myList = obj as List<MyClass>;
                int no = 1;
                foreach (MyClass entry in myList)
                {
                    writer.Write("Entry {0}: PropertyA={1} PropertyB={2}\n",
                            no++,
                            entry.PropertyA,
                            entry.PropertyB);
                }
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException ex)
        {
            writer.Write(SystemInfo.NullText);
        }
    }
}
```

**2)** How would I configure this in my Log4Net.config file? I've got:

```
<renderer renderingClass="MyNamespace.ListOfMyClassRenderer" renderedClass="System.Collections.IList<MyClass>" />
```

**3)** A final question. If I wanted to write each entry to a log4net property how would I do this? Should I use the RendererMap?

Answer (score 4):

The following link is a **[Better Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844163/how-to-configure-log4net-custom-object-renderer-for-generic-objects)**. Keeping my question for completeness:

**1)** This can be done by making a renderer of IList and asking what generics it is using. We won't be able to make one renderer class per generics, but works.

```
class MyListRenderer : IObjectRenderer
{
    public void RenderObject(RendererMap rendererMap, object obj, TextWriter writer)
    {
        var myList = obj as IList<MyClass>;
        if (myList != null) {
            try
            {
                int no = 1;
                foreach (MyClass entry in myList)
                {
                    writer.Write("Entry {0}: PropertyA={1} PropertyB={2}\n",
                            no++,
                            entry.PropertyA,
                            entry.PropertyB);
                }
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException ex)
            {
                writer.Write(SystemInfo.NullText);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            new DefaultRenderer().RenderObject(rendererMap, obj, writer);
        }
    }
}
```

Notice how we are using the default renderer if everything else fails. This retains the default IList rendering. Might have extended the DefaultRenderer() but it is sealed.

**2)** This can be configured by using

```
<renderer renderingClass="MyNamespace.MyListRenderer" renderedClass="System.Collections.IList" />
```

**3)** Doesn't seem like it is possible to set log4net properties with a object renderer.